# Solving a differential equation: $y^4 \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^4 = (y^2-1)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would one go ahead solving the following for these conditions: (i) passes through $(0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ and (ii) $(0,\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})$ :

$$y^4 \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^4 = (y^2-1)^2$$

There is something going on with the signs here when we take the LHS and RHS to the power of $1/4$ here. I can't quite figure out what.

Comment: $$(\frac{dy}{dx})^4 = \frac{(y^2 - 1)^2}{y^4}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}}{y}$$

$$\pm \frac{y}{{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}}}\;dy \;=\; dx$$

$$\pm \sqrt{y^2 - 1} \;=\; x + C$$

$$y^2 \;=\; (x+C)^2 + 1$$

$$y \;=\; \sqrt{(x + C)^2+1} $$

Now you just have to apply the conditions and find "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(yy')^4=(y^2-1)^2$$
$$(yy')^2=\pm(y^2-1)$$
$$yy'=\pm\sqrt{\pm(y^2-1)}$$
$Y=y^2$
$$\frac{1}{2}Y'=\pm\sqrt{\pm(Y-1)}$$
$$\frac{dY}{\pm 2\sqrt{\pm(Y-1)}}=dx$$
$$\pm\sqrt{\pm(Y-1)}=x+c$$
$$Y=1\pm(x+c)^2$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{1\pm(x+c)^2}$$
Condition $y(0)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=+\sqrt{1- c^2} \qquad\to\qquad c=\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Condition $y(0)=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}=+\sqrt{1+ c^2} \qquad\to\qquad c=\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Solution :
$$y(x)=\sqrt{1\pm\left(x\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$